# How to append a group of lines after another group of lines?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to transform this text from:

```
Chapter 1. Horse
Chapter 2. Orange
Chapter 3. Computer
/1
/2
/3
```

to

```
Chapter 1. Horse/1
Chapter 2. Orange/2
Chapter 3. Computer/3
```

I'm not sure if regex is useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(Chapter (\d+).+)|/\d+)$`
- Replace with: `(?1$1/$2:)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:               # non captre group
    (               # start group 1
      Chapter       # literally Chapter followed by a space
      (\d+)         # group 2, 1 or more digits
      .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
    )               # end group 1
  |               # OR
    /\d+            # a slash followed by 1 or more digits
  )                 # end group
$                   # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
  $1        # take it
  /         # a slash
  $2        # content of group 2
  :         # else, nothing
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with Regex, or Notepad++.

But there is a simple solution.

Save your file as .csv first, then use Microsoft Excel, or another spreadsheet editor, such as OpenOffice Calc to open the CSV file. Make a selection of the second group and move it to the second column besides the first group where the data of the second group is supposed to go.

Save your file.

Now, open the file in notepad++ and use search/replace to get it back into the format you wish to use.